# Javascript function not working cross-browser.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8

This is my javascript function that is working in chrome and FF5 but not working in IE.

```
function createContorl() {
    var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");

    parentDiv.setAttribute("class", "ModelProgressDiv");
    parentDiv.setAttribute("Id", "ProgressDiv");

    var innerContent = document.createElement("div");

    innerContent.setAttribute("class", "ModalProgressDivContent");

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.setAttribute("src", "images/loading_large.gif");
    parentDiv.appendChild(innerContent);

    innerContent.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);
}
```

Comment: `parentDiv.setAttribute("Id", "ProgressDiv");` should be lower-case `id`. If this does not help, wrap your function in **try..catch** block and alert the error.

Comment: The part of code you displayed is working for me, might be there are some problem with the class you have mentioned. Check with the css

Comment: AmGates @: Dear its working for me also but only in chrome and ff5 not in ie5  and my calss is here ModelProgressDiv
    {
        z-index: 10005;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: wait; 
  top:0%; 
  background-color: #ffffff; 
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
   -moz-opacity: .5; 
  height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center; 
        
        } and  .ModalProgressDivContent
    {
       padding: 10px; 
   border: solid 0px #000040; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   background-color:#ffffff;
   margin-top:300px;
    }

Comment: What exactly _not worked_? If error: message, line? Image is not loading? Or ?

Comment: @Davide - so how exactly will jQuery fix the OP's issue?

Answer (score 2):

`setAttribute` is broken in IE unless you are using a very recent version in Standards Mode. It sets properties instead of attributes so it fails when the property doesn't have the same name as the attribute. Don't use it.

```
parentDiv.className = "ModelProgressDiv"; // etc
```

Comment: @naval - Get rid of *setAttribute* altogether, just set DOM properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on IE8: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFK77/2/)

BTW, please check the in the function name `createContorl` but that would cause problem in all browsers.

Perhaps, you should explain when you say "not working in IE".